# React native image cropping in IOS

Tags: react-native

Currently im using react-native-image-crop-picker React native Free styled image cropping is not enabled in IOS.Crop of picture does not allow a true crop, it lets you move pic around within a narrow given frame but it cuts off parts of the photo. You cannot adjust with zoom in or zoom out. There should be a grid. Can anyone suggest how to use free styled image cropping in ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend the following:

`react-native-android-image-cropper` on Android and 
`react-native-image-cropping` on iOS